# Format of csv file as output of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have created a data frame and I am trying to print the output of
the data frame in a CSV file. Below is my code. The issue is the format of
output in CSV as it is not as I expected. Below is what I was not expecting. I am new to coding in Python, hence not sure what is the solution
here.

```
> 1.[] for each and every element output
> 2. Snapshot date is not in date format
> 3. new line after each iteration
> 4. Header is absent
```

Result

```
"[datetime.date(2020, 8, 3)]",['https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/M2E13227MBE2?postcode=2000'],['M2E13227MBE2'],[2000],['SR'],['Business Market'],['Commander Power & Gas'],['M2E'],['NSW'],['2020-07-01'],[11.6],[''],[193.1818],[''],[''],[22.2454],[''],[''],['']

"[datetime.date(2020, 8, 3)]",['https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/POW15474MBE3?postcode=2000'],['POW15474MBE3'],[2000],['TOUCL'],['Powerdirect Business Rate Saver'],['Powerdirect'],['POW'],['NSW'],['2020-07-01'],[9.5],[''],[152.45],[7.14],[9.92],[''],[8.56],[38.94],[17.73]

"[datetime.date(2020, 8, 3)]",['https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/PWR93178MBE1?postcode=2000'],['PWR93178MBE1'],[2000],['SRCL'],['Powerbank Bis Flat + CLoad + Smart'],['Powerclub'],['PWR'],['NSW'],['2020-07-15'],[''],[''],[192.1417],[11.589],[''],[17.9203],[''],[''],['']

"[datetime.date(2020, 8, 3)]",['https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/DEN82306MBE1?postcode=2000'],['DEN82306MBE1'],[2000],['TOUCL'],['Ausgrid Small Business TOU + CL Smart Saver'],['Discover Energy'],['DEN'],['NSW'],['2020-07-01'],[6],[23],[175],[13.54],[''],[''],[17],[47.9],[24.23]

"[datetime.date(2020, 8, 3)]",['https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/PWR93173MBE1?postcode=2000'],['PWR93173MBE1'],[2000],['SR'],['Powerbank Bis Flat'],['Powerclub'],['PWR'],['NSW'],['2020-07-15'],[''],[''],[162.9629],[''],[''],[17.9203],[''],[''],['']
```

Code

```
data_plan = {'Snapshot_Date': [Snapshot_Date], 'API': [API], 'planId': [planId], 'postcode': [postcode],
                 'tariffType': [tariffType], 'planName': [planName], 'retailerName': [retailerName],
                 'retailerCode': [retailerCode], 'state': [state], 'effectiveDate': [effectiveDate],
                 'solarFit': [solarFit], 'discount': [discount], 'dailySupplyCharge': [dailySupplyCharge],
                 'Controlled_Load_1': [Controlled_Load_1], 'Controlled_Load_2': [Controlled_Load_2],
                 'Single_Rate': [Single_Rate], 'Off_Peak': [Off_Peak], 'Peak': [Peak], 'Shoulder': [Shoulder]}
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data=data_plan)
    with open("df1.csv",'a') as csvfile:
        writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
        row=[data_plan['Snapshot_Date'],data_plan['API'],data_plan['planId'], data_plan['postcode'],
                 data_plan['tariffType'], data_plan['planName'], data_plan['retailerName'],
                 data_plan['retailerCode'],data_plan['state'],data_plan['effectiveDate'],
                 data_plan['solarFit'],data_plan['discount'], data_plan['dailySupplyCharge'],
                 data_plan['Controlled_Load_1'],data_plan['Controlled_Load_2'],data_plan['Single_Rate'],
             data_plan['Off_Peak'],data_plan['Peak'],data_plan['Shoulder']]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: why aren't you using `df.to_csv()`?

Comment: `[]` is not normal element in CSV and you can get it only as part of string ie `"['https:/...']"`. OR create list in cell `['https:/...']` and it will put it as string `['https:/...']`